# Rails - how to update existing record in database with a newly created object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am fetching data from CSV files and saving them to the database. Here's the simplified code structure (it's a rake task):

```
... loading CSV tools...
car = Car.new
car.tender_load_id = data.element[8]
car.brand = data.element[2]
car.color = 'green'
...
car.build_car_metadata(mbol: help_var[:mbol], ...)
car.first_registration = data.element[21]

car.skip_registration_code_validation = true # for not creating registration_code

if existing_car = Car.where("cars.tender_load_id ILIKE ?", "%#{car.tender_load_id}%").first
  # car already exists => update
  existing_car.update(car)
  puts "Car exists, updating car with ID #{existing_car.id}."
else
  car.save!            
end
```

When I run this take task, I get the following error message:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `reject' for #<Car:0x007fa3e2063a78>
```

and it points out to this line:

```
existing_car.update(car)
```

How do I make this work? I unfortunately cannot place the `if-else` part on the beginning of the rake task, the structure needs to be like this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @anothe
no, will not "return" true if no record found. i'd add parens though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the existing car with just the attributes, you can not pass in a full model.

Build the attributes, then create or update depending on whether a car exists already:

```
attributes = {}
attributes[:color] = ...
attributes[:brand] = ...
attributes[:tender_load_id] = ...


if (car = Car.where("cars.tender_load_id ILIKE ?", "%#{attributes[:tender_load_id]}%").first)
  car.update(attributes)
else
  Car.create!(attributes)
end
```

Note 1: It seems there can be multiple cars with the same `tender_load_id`. This means that the query for existing car will return an arbitrary record. Perhaps you want to add an `order` to that query.

Note 2: The way you query seems brittle. Isn't there a better ID in the CSV?

Note 3: attributes ending in `_id` are usually foreign keys. So perhaps find a better name for this attribute.

Comment: Hi @Pascal, thank you for the answer. Because the `Car` model has too many attributes, I converted them with `car.attributes.except!("id")` and it works like a charm. However, is there a way to automatically update also models with the `has_many` relations?

Comment: Can you give more details about the relations you'd want to update?

Comment: All of them are `Car` -> has_many -> `car_metadata` and so on.